# When i output escaped htmlspecialchars string the HTML entities does not show?

Tags: php, utf-8, escaping, htmlspecialchars

Hi i am currently working on a system where users will be able to submit comments.

The problem is that the HTML entities does not show as they are supposed to when i echo the escaped string, but for some reason if i include the copyright html entitie in the footer it shows and works just fine?

**The string submitted**

```
Why can't i submit this
```

**The string outputted**

```
Why can&#39;t i submit this
```

The output will look like this, which is not what i want.
[image]

Function to escape string

```
function escape($text) {
    return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

I use this to make sure my website uses UTF-8

**Meta tag**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

**.htaccess**

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddCharset UTF-8 .htm .html .css .js .woff
```

**Connection**

```
define("DB_SERVER", "mysql:host=myhost;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8");
define("DB_USER", "my user");
define("DB_PASS", "my password");
define("DB_NAME", "my database");

function dbCon() {
    try {
        $dbCon = new PDO(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
//        echo $ex->getMessage();
        echo "An error has occured";
    }
    return $dbCon;
}
```

Comment: Ummm `ENT_QUOTES` will convert both `'` and `"` to their HTML entity equivalents - it's doing exactly what you're telling it to... you want either `ENT_COMPAT` or `ENT_NOQUOTES`

Comment: The entity does not show as an entity? is that supposed to be the case ?

Comment: but if you're viewing the HTML entity in a web browser it'll render `&#39;` as `'` - which are you seeing when you *View Source* ? Use *View Source* rather than *Inspect Element* - one shows you the code, the other the DOM.

Comment: Thats the problem it does not render it that way... look at the image i just submitted up in the question

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 Are you using chrome? Check your header for content-type and make sure it is UTF8

Comment: Aaah - looks like double-encoding: if you view the source you'll *probably* see `&amp;#39;` as the initial `&` has been encoded; like it's run through `htmlspecialchars()` twice.

Comment: &amp;#39; ehmm so i am using my escape function twice or what are you stating :) ?

Comment: Thats just weird because it is only getting escaped once, i can see the escape 2 lines above. hmm

Comment: Try `htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);` <- the final *false* flag  turns off double-encoding.

Comment: Bravo! thats it, but how do i find out why it was getting escaped more than once? it is litterally getting escaped 2 lines above just once for a newly created variable

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 1.) Are you inserting comment to DB? 2.) Are you using htmlspecialchars before insert to DB? If so, you shouldn't....

Comment: If your goal is to prevent XSS, you should store the input without escaping, then call `escape()` when displaying it. This will encode things like `<` so they're displayed literally, rather than being interpreted as HTML tags.

Comment: I am storing it without escaping i am only sanitsizing the data before storing it :)